# Como posso transformar uma string em float?

Tags: python-3.x, string, float, replace

Estou fazendo um trabalho e me deparei com a seguinte situação: tenho uma lista com números decimais. Porém a lista está como uma string.
Por exemplo:

```
h = ["3,5","4,3","8,9"]
```

Agora aparece meu problema, preciso que a string se torne um float, para poder realizar uma conta parecida com a que está abaixo:

```
#este trecho de código é apenas um exemplo da conta
p = [3.5, 20.4, 7.2]
y = 50
m = []
for i in range(len(p)):
    m.append(y/p[i])
print(m)
```

Porém pude notar que há dois problemas. Primeiro a lista h (que é uma string) deveria ser um float. E segundo, como sabemos, números decimais devem ser separados por "." quando são float.

Eu pensei na seguinte situação. Primeiramente preciso mudar a "," dos decimais para ".", e com isso eu poderei transformar tranquilamente de str para float.

Para mudar a "," para "." tentei usar .replace da seguinte maneira:

```
h = ["3,5","4,3","8,9"]
print(type(h))

h = str(h).strip("[]")
h = h.replace(",", ".")
print(type(h),h)
```

Acabou funcionando até demais, porque todas as vírgulas foram substituidas. Inclusive as que deveriam se manter para fazer a separação. O que quero dizer é:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'> '3.5'. '4.3'. '8.9'     #esses foram os resultados dos prints
```

Depois tentei transformar em float, mas não vai. Até tentei dar append em uma lista vazia para ver se conseguia trasnformar em float, porém sempre da erro.

```
h = ["3,5","4,3","8,9"]
print(type(h))
ju = []

h = str(h).strip("[]")
h = h.replace(",", ".")
h = float(h)                  #ValueError: could not convert string to float: "'3.5'. '4.3'. '8.9'"
print(type(h),h)                 # caso eu coloque a linha do h = float(h) em comentário,
                                 # aparece como none a nova lista
ju = ju.append(h)
print(type(ju))               #<class 'NoneType'> None
```

Agora estou empacado nisso, não sei como prosseguir. Por favor, imploro ajuda de algum guru do Python.

Comment: É isso que vc quer? `[str(float(i.replace(",", "."))) for i in h]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se tu quer transformar cada valor do aray em float, basta fazer isso:

```
h = [ float(x.strip("[]").replace(",", ".")) for x in h ]
```

Para cara elemento do teu array, tu remove os espaços, muda a vírgula para ponto e transforma em float, conseguindo um array de floats.

Além disso, na linha onde tu faz

```
h = float(h)
```

Tu está tentando converter em float um array, em vez de uma string.

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma interessante de resolver esta questão é utilizando o seguinte código:

```
h = ["3,5", "4,3", "8,9"]
m = [round(50 / float(i.replace(',', '.')), 2) for i in h]
print(m)
```

Observe que quando executamos este código será executado o estrutura `for` do `list comprehension`. Neste momento é executado a seguinte instrução: **for i in h**, pega **i**, converta a vírgula - `,` - para ponto - `.`. Em seguida, pega este valor e o converte para `float`. Depois realiza a divisão de `50 / float()` e, depois arredonda o valor para duas casas decimais.

Depois de ter realizado todas estas operações é exibido a lista `m`, contendo valores float com duas casas decimais.

**Observação**

Uma vez que percebi que os valores produzidos por `50 / float` iria produzir valores com mais de 6 casas decimais, resolvi utilizar a função round() para arredondar os valores para duas casas decimais.

Comment: achei interessante, agradeço pela ajuda